# Could not resolve host: content.dropboxapi.com when to upload file at shutdown

Tags: shutdown, systemd, dropbox

I want to upload a file to my dropbox when my pc is shutting down.

```
sudo vim  /etc/systemd/system/upload.service
[Unit]
Description=upload files into dropbox
Before=network.target shutdown.target  reboot.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStop=/bin/true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh 
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the upload.sh script.

```
cd  /home
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
            --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" \
            --header "Dropbox-API-Arg:  {\"path\":\"/test.txt\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}" \
            --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
            --data-binary @"test.txt"
```

`bash upload.sh` can executed successfully,and `test.txt` file uploaded into my dropbox.

```
sudo systemctl enable upload service
```

To reboot my pc.

```
sudo journalctl -u upload 

Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost systemd[1]: Started upload files into dropbox.
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost systemd[1]: Starting upload files into dropbox...
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost bash[117]: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost bash[117]: Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost bash[117]: 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: content.dropboxapi.com; Un
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost systemd[1]: upload.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=6/NOTCONFIGURED
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost systemd[1]: Unit upload.service entered failed state.
Apr 13 23:58:52 localhost systemd[1]: upload.service failed.
```

Some DNS error `Could not resolve host: content.dropboxapi.com` result in upload.service failed.

I have added `Requires=network-online.target` in upload.service,how to make DNS parser resolve the host at my pc's shutdowning time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method 1:  /etc/systemd/system/upload.service
1.1  /etc/systemd/system/upload.service

```
sudo vim  /etc/systemd/system/upload.service
[Unit]
Description=upload files into dropbox
Before=shutdown.target  reboot.target
Requires=network-online.target
After=network.target    

[Service]
ExecStop=/bin/true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh 
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

1.2  vim  /home/upload.sh

```
cd  /home
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
            --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" \
            --header "Dropbox-API-Arg:  {\"path\":\"/test.txt\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}" \
            --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
            --data-binary @"test.txt"
```

1.3    `sudo systemctl enable upload.service`

method 2:  /lib/systemd/system-shutdown/upload.service
2.1  /lib/systemd/system-shutdown/upload.service

```
sudo vim  /lib/systemd/system-shutdown/upload.service
[Unit]
Description=upload files into dropbox
Before=shutdown.target  reboot.target
Requires=network-online.target
After=network.target    

[Service]
ExecStop=/bin/true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh 
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2.2  vim  /home/upload.sh

```
cd  /home
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
            --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" \
            --header "Dropbox-API-Arg:  {\"path\":\"/test.txt\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}" \
            --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
            --data-binary @"test.txt"
```

2.3    `sudo systemctl enable /lib/systemd/system-shutdown/upload.service`

Answer (score 0):

### Execstop and Execstart reversed

According to this Unix & Linux answer: [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), your Execstop and Execstart are reversed.

The lines:

```
ExecStop=/bin/true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh
```

Should read:

```
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh
```

The answer goes on to mention to restart services. So after creating the file, make sure to `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl enable yourservice --now`

---

#### Alternate method not working

The `before=`, `requires=`, etc. can be confusing at times. You can put your script in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` directory instead. It will be run immediately upon shutdown. See: https://superuser.com/questions/1016827/how-do-i-run-a-script-before-everything-else-on-shutdown-with-systemd

The `/usr` prefix may be different on some systems, ie just start directory name with `/lib`.

Comment: Please try in your pc,the same error as before.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I revised the answer and added `systemd` method based on your question. The old answer was deprecated to "Alternate" section. Note the answer you accepted appears to have `start` and `stop` reversed??

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run a program or script while the system is going down is by using the `ExecStop=` of the unit to run such program. The `ExecStart=` can either be a dummy script (such as `/bin/true`) or, in recent versions of systemd, it can even be omitted.

Regarding dependencies, you want to place your unit **after** the services you need, such as `network-online.target` and perhaps `systemd-resolved.service` if you're using it for DNS resolution. The reason for that is that systems are stopped at shutdown time in the reverse order in which they are started. So by ordering your service **after** the dependencies, it means your `ExecStop=` script will be run **before** the dependencies are stopped.

Something like this should work:

```
[Unit]
Description=upload files into dropbox
After=network.target systemd-resolved.service
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/upload.sh 
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the unit as usual (the `--now` argument also starts it):

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now upload.service
```

And it will perform the upload when **stopped**, which you can test with:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop upload.service
```

This was recently [discussed](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-March/040558.html) in the systemd-devel mailing list.